# need understanding for Angular routing's when method

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, single-page-application

Hi All I am new to angularJs , I am finding it hard to understand the routing concept, I learnt from many sources , but still it's not quite clear specially the when method. What i understood is routing helps us to achieve single page application , which means browser loads only one .html file and then other contents are removed or added based on user's interaction, no other file gets loaded. But in the following definition from the link [angular routing](http://websystique.com/angularjs/angularjs-routing-tutorial-using-ngroute/)

**templateUrl: When the HTML to be displayed is complex and large, it’s better to break them into separate templates/files, and give the URL to the HTML file as the templateUrl. AngularJS loads the HTML file from the server when it needs to display the particular route.**

It says angularjs loads the HTML file as the templateUrl. Could someone please explain this to me ?

Answer (score 0):

1.The **templateUrl** property tells which HTML template AngularJS should load and display inside the `div` with the `ngView` directive.

2.It can be path (or) function and .when() method takes a path and a route as parameters.

3.It can be use as function with returning generated URL. We can manipulate url with passing argument which takes route.

```
.when('/:screenName/getAll',{
    templateUrl: function(route){
         return route.screenName +'/getAllList'
    }
})
```

So, it is not like reloading the whole html page.Only the html content is loaded inside the `div`.. Hopes this help.!!!

Comment: Ok... I understood this but even ajax does that then why do we have routing.. Sorry I am getting a little confused how ajax and routing are different ?

Comment: Routing is the process where a piece of software looks at the URL and uses it to decide what bit of code to run.

Routing is not an alternative to Ajax, it is something that can trigger Ajax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848006/how-routing-and-ajax-are-different-in-angularjs

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
//main.js
$routeProvider.when('/computers', {
    templateUrl: 'views/computers.html',
});


//./views/computers.html
<ul>
    <li>Computer 1</li>
    <li>Computer 2</li>
</ul>
```

When the route is `http://example.com/#/computers`, AngularJs will loads the `./views/computers.html` file by ajax, and cache it for the others requests. So, it's not only one (the main) html file that will load in your SPA.

Answer (score -2):

Angular loads the html file as the template url means that it use the path you provide to load the html. This would be more organized compared to writing the html in angular components.

Single page app does not means angular loads just only one file. When users interacts, routing may be executed, more data will be loaded, and more html or some portions of html will be loaded combined with data to render to users.

The "when" method means that when users visit a defined route, things followed will be proceed, including the "templateUrl".