# How routing and Ajax are different in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, single-page-application

I am new to angular and I am trying to understand the routing concept , but I am getting confused routing is used to load some parts of the html from server if templateUrl is given in when method but even ajax does that it loads data in the form of JSON, XML or HTML from the server without reloading the entire page.So how are they different ?

Answer (score 0):

Routing is the process where a piece of software looks at the URL and uses it to decide what bit of code to run.

In Angular, quite a lot of time, the "bit of code" that gets run will include an Ajax request to get some data from the server.

Routing is not an alternative to Ajax, it is something that can trigger Ajax.

Comment: But in routing syntax we are not using "$http" anywhere which is used in angular for ajax process , also we can simply use ajax then what is the need of routing at all?

Comment: "But in routing syntax we are not using "$http" anywhere which is used in angular for ajax process" — Then you probably aren't getting additional data from the server (or you are looking in the wrong place, since routing happens at the controller level and Ajax happens at the model level).

Comment: "also we can simply use ajax then what is the need of routing at all" — So you can have bookmarkable/linkable URLs and so that the back and forward buttons in the browser work.

Comment: Ok... so routing is not for data exchange between client and server when that is needed it is done only by ajax, routing is only for modifying any part of the HTML kindly correct me if I am wrong .

Comment: The purpose of routing is described in the first paragraph of the answer.